# Sympy get vector from vector field

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm using sympy (which is awesome) and I just made a vector field like this

```
> import sympy
> from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
> from sympy import *
> R = CoordSys3D('R')
> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
> v = x*R.i + 4*z*R.j + y*R.k
x*R.i + 4*z*R.j + y*R.k
> v.evalf(subs={x:6, y:5, z:2})
6.00000000000000*R.i + 8.00000000000000*R.j + 5.00000000000000*R.k
```

and what I need is to get a vector or list of the form [6.0,8.0,5.0], so is there a way to get a list form `v.evalf()`? I could use use split or something on `"6.00000000000000*R.i + 8.00000000000000*R.j + 5.00000000000000*R.k"` but thats seems ugly and maybe there a built in method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [252]: vector = v.evalf(subs={x:6, y:5, z:2}); vector
Out[252]: 6.00000000000000*R.i + 8.00000000000000*R.j + 5.00000000000000*R.k

In [253]: list(vector.to_matrix(R))
Out[253]: [6.00000000000000, 8.00000000000000, 5.00000000000000]
```

---

Other possibilities include

```
In [256]: vector.as_poly().coeffs()
Out[256]: [6.00000000000000, 8.00000000000000, 5.00000000000000]

In [257]: list(vector.components.values())
Out[257]: [5.00000000000000, 8.00000000000000, 6.00000000000000]
```

but I think they suffer a fatal flaw which is exposed when one or more of the components equal 0. For example, if `z` is set to 0:

```
In [258]: vector = v.evalf(subs={x:6, y:5, z:0}); vector
Out[258]: 6.00000000000000*R.i + 5.00000000000000*R.k
```

Then `list(vector.to_matrix(R))` still returns 3 components:

```
In [259]: list(vector.to_matrix(R))
Out[259]: [6.00000000000000, 0, 5.00000000000000]
```

while these other two expressions omit the zero-component:

```
In [260]: vector.as_poly().coeffs()
Out[260]: [6.00000000000000, 5.00000000000000]

In [261]: list(vector.components.values())
Out[261]: [5.00000000000000, 6.00000000000000]
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks just want I wanted, my code is working `list(v.evalf(subs={x:i, y:j, z:k}).to_matrix(R))`, but I was thinking of another thing, can I use lambdify ? because I believe that would be efficient. What I tried was `f = sympy.lambdify([x,y,z], v)` and then `f(2,1,5)` but here raise and error: `'Symbol' object has no attribute 'i'`

Comment: `lambdify` is useful for converting sympy operations into, say, NumPy or mpmath operations so that certain numeric computations can be done faster. Here, the values are in the `_component` attribute of the `Vector` instance. Accessing these components has to be done at the Python level  -- at the very least, a call to `__getattr__`. I don't see any place for NumPy or mpmath to help speed things up.